# datagrid property window not showing the row related things(means rowcommand,rowdatabound...)Why?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Iam using vb 2005,sqlserver 2005,vb.net web application

in my datagrid properties window not showing the rowcommand..

I need create row command/..

Why its not showing?

Answer (score 1):

The designer sometimes misses it, don't know why but you can manually type it in.

ASP.Net:

```
<asp:GridView OnRowCommand="ProductsGridView_RowCommand" />
```

CODE BEHIND:

```
Sub ProductsGridView_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewCommandEventArgs)

End Sub
```

Comment: manually wrote code but the rowcommand not fires... and  iam using datagrid not gridview. please help me.. its very urgent.

Comment: datagrid is not part of the normal asp.net tools, the windows forms etc. equivalent is called datagrid, but on asp.net it's called the gridview, is it a third party tool?